# Sequelize.js Add Enum from existed array

Tags: enums, sequelize.js

I want to create an Enum in table, but it's very long.

`var nations = ['AC', 'AZ', 'BD'....]`

If put it in sequelize.define() directly, it's ugly.
Can I define an array first, then pass into sequelize.define()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
var nations = ['AC', 'AZ', 'BD'....]

sequelize.define('foo', {
  bar: DataTypes.ENUM(nations)
});
```

Comment: It's so easy, why I'm silly when I tried last time?! Thx!